# Reset changes to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am using a function to determine the color and brightness of a dynamic number of divs. Whenever I enter that div with my mouse, it a) is assigned a random color and b) becomes 10% darker. Now, when I re-run the function, I would expect all of the div's brightness (i.e. the values in the array "brightness") to be reset to 1. However, the browser keeps their last value (i.e. they remain dark), instead of reseting them. Why is that?

Best regards

Beni

```js
//randomColor function is taken from http://www.devcurry.com/2010/08/generate-random-colors-using-javascript.html //
  function randomRgb(value) {

  col =  "rgb("
  + randomColor(255) * value + ","
  + randomColor(255) * value + ","
  + randomColor(255) * value + ")";
  }

  function randomColor(num) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
  }

  function resetColorOfBoxes() {
    boxes = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    boxes.forEach(box => box.style.backgroundColor = "white");
  }

  function resetBrightness() {
    brightness.forEach(brightness[i] = 1);
  }

  function promptEntry() {

    let userInput = prompt("How many rows would you like?", "Enter a number");

    if (isNaN(userInput)) {
      alert("That's not a valid entry. Try again");
      promptEntry();
    }

    else {
      createGrid(userInput);
    }
  }

  function createGrid(numberOfRows) {

    resetColorOfBoxes();

    let gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat('+numberOfRows+', 1fr)'

    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = gridTemplateColumns;
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = gridTemplateColumns;

    let brightness = [];

    let i = 0;
    let numberOfBoxes = numberOfRows**2;


    /*Create boxes*/
    for (i; i < numberOfBoxes ; i++) {
      brightness[i+1] = 1;
      console.log(brightness);

      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.classList.add(i+1);
      document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);

      div.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
        var className = this.className;
        brightness[className] = brightness[className] - 0.1;
        console.log(brightness[className]);
        randomRgb(brightness[className]);
        this.style.backgroundColor = col;
      });
    }
  }

  let btn = document.getElementById("start")
  btn.addEventListener("click", promptEntry)
```

```html
<h1>Etch-a-sketch</h1>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Perhaps look at onload? https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the function `resetBrightness()` but it is not used anywhere in the code you posted. So that could be a potential issue.

However, assuming that you are using it, you are declaring `let brightness = [];` inside your `createGrid()` function which will render the array useless if used outside the function because it is a local variable used by `createGrid()`

To solve your issue, you can either modify your `resetBrightness()` function to accept the brightness array as a parameter and modify the array within the function or set the array as a global variable.